# Default constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

if i have constructors with parameters in my class,
we need to provide a do-nothing constructor like :

**1)**

```
class A
{
  A(){};  //To satisfy the compiler
  //some constructors with parameter
};
```

just to satisfy the compiler.

Now if my class has a default parameter like :

**2)**

```
class A
{
//A(){} can't be used expilcilty or implicilty
A(int = 0);
};
A a;
```

There is going to be an ambiguity whether to call A::() or A::A(int = 0) so we cannnot provide any do-nothing constructor in the second case.
So is it true that even the implicit constructor provided by the compiler gets suppresed in this case.

Please provide some clarification/thoughts.

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify a zero-arg constructor to "satisfy the compiler".

Comment: Programming was never about satisfying the compiler!

Comment: You don't have to have a default constructor to satisfy the compiler.  You need to have one if you're going to do something that requires a default constructor, something like `A a;` or `A b[10];` or `A * c = new A[10];`.  There is no requirement that a class have a default constructor.

Comment: it seems the book I was reading minutes ago has errors, it had those words...to satisfy the compiler...Thanks for letting me know all this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constructor with no parameters, or a constructor where **all** parameters have a default value, **is** the default construcor.

The compiler will not generate one if you have provided it.

You don't have to provide a default constructor if that doesn't make sense for your type. Of course that prohibits the use of your class in places where a default constructor is needed, but such use probably doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler only generates a default ctor if you do not explicitly define one.  So if you define a ctor, the compiler will not generate a ctor for the class.

Comment: And it doesn't matter how many parameters, default or not, your ctor has, the compiler will not generate one if you specify any (aside from the copy and move ctor).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to explicitly disable the use of a constructor, you can make it `private` to the class.

Note that the compiler shouldn't be whinging about you not providing a constructor. The minute you provide one - and only one - it should automatically *stop* providing the default constructor